# WinApi WndProc's Timer procedure issue

Tags: winapi

I've got a question about the WndProc's Timer procedure functionality.
What if Display_function haven't finished yet after that function called by timer, what happens what if next TM_TIMER function was called in time but it still running Display_function.?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
static HANDLE hTimer;
switch (iMessage)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
switch (LOWORD(wParam))
{
case 0:

hTimer = (HANDLE)SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 10, NULL); //10ms
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, 0); 
break;

....
case WM_TIMER:
switch (wParam)
{
case 1:
Display_function(hWnd); 
break;
}
```

Comment: Everyone seems to be using [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) the wrong way. The *nIDEvent* parameter is pointer-sized for a reason. The safe way to set up a pointer with a unique ID is to pass the address of a (local) variable. That way the ID never collides with another timer ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer messages are synthesised when you retrieve messages from the message queue. They cannot interrupt the thread from its task.

The timer messages are typically synthesised by your calls to `GetMessage` from your main message loop.

Comment: Thanks But I didn't get it exactly,  you which means Display_function can  not interrupted by timer before it finish. am I right?

Comment: @grander2 - yes, of course Display_function  wiil not be interrupted

Comment: Correct. It's your code that calls GetMessage. So long as you don't dispatch messages in the Display_function then there will be no re-entrancy.